# Verification error

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-id

Having trouble with an iPhone 6s running 10.2.1

It won't accept a password for iTunes, App Store or iCloud. Tried rebooting and then logging out of iTunes. Problem now is it won't allow me to log back in and I get no response by clicking reset username or password.

Very frustrating. If it makes a difference I do not have wifi access only cellular data.  Can I test my Apple ID another way?

Answer (score 1):

Before you call your cellular carrier to be sure they're not somehow blocking, try to log in to http://discussions.apple.com

That should verify you have internet access and the AppleID itself is active. If not - you'll need help from Apple Support to reset your account or investigate if it's locked. (Or the carrier to get you connected to the internet)

Assuming you can log in, I would put the device in AirPlane mode and then change the date/time to be about a minute off what you think the time is.

> settings > general > date & time

Then disable AirPlane mode and re-enable automatic time setting and see that the carrier gets your device to the correct time.

At that point, try the iCloud preference pane. That should get you a decent chance that the device re-connects to the services. [Unless there is a service outage](https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/) - you should have a specific error message at this point to track down for iCloud settings (or whichever of the other items using your AppleID you start with after resetting the time and network connections).